# Media queries in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can anyone explain me on the header, footer, main and left and right aside formed here using flex box.

```
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
   .aside { flex: 1 auto; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
   .main    { flex: 2 0px; }
   .aside-1 { order: 1; } 
   .main    { order: 2; }
   .aside-2 { order: 3; }
   .footer  { order: 4; }
}
```

I am not able to understand the two media queries used here and how it helps to create this layout. When i remove the code, its all stacked. Can anyone explain me those two media queries and how it helps in bringing this layout.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvmFK

Comment: This is example was taken from here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/